# Why can't Visual Studio find System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting these 11 errors in Visual Studio:

```
Error   456 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   457 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\WebMatrix.WebData.resources.dll" because it was not found.    ViMuDat
Error   458 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\WebMatrix.Data.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   459 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.WebPages.resources.dll" because it was not found.  ViMuDat
Error   460 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.resources.dll" because it was not found.    ViMuDat
Error   461 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   462 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.WebPages.Administration.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   463 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.Razor.resources.dll" because it was not found. ViMuDat
Error   464 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\System.Web.Helpers.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   465 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\NuGet.Core.resources.dll" because it was not found.   ViMuDat
Error   466 Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\de\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.resources.dll" because it was not found. ViMuDat
```

I try to build a project that was developed with Visual Studio 2010, but I am using Visual Studio 2012. If I build it twice, it works without errors.

**How can I fix that?**

I have found [Bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC 3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) and [_bin_deployableAssemblies and MSBuild](http://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/_bin_deployableassemblies-and-msbuild/), but I could not manage to fix those errors. Could somebody please explain step by step what I should do? I am new to C# and Visual Studio.

I think this error is also the problem why I can't Check in the project into a TFS.

I have these assemblies in my `bin` folder:

```
D:\...\bin> ls
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        18.12.2012     23:53            de
-a---        15.12.2012     21:11     783648 EntityFramework.dll
-a---        15.12.2012     21:11     834489 EntityFramework.xml
-a---        18.12.2012     23:53      42496 LumenWorks.Framework.IO.dll
-a---        18.12.2012     23:53     116224 LumenWorks.Framework.IO.pdb
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31      53640 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotati
                                             ons.dll
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31    1328984 System.Data.dll
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31     919880 System.dll
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31      24944 System.Web.Abstractions.dll
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31    2824528 System.Web.dll
-a---        05.01.2011     14:45     130408 System.Web.Helpers.dll
-a---        03.05.2012     08:55      37861 System.Web.Helpers.xml
-a---        05.01.2011     16:42     445280 System.Web.Mvc.dll
-a---        03.05.2012     08:51     777665 System.Web.Mvc.xml
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31      24928 System.Web.Routing.dll
-a---        05.01.2011     14:45     136552 System.Web.WebPages.dll
-a---        03.05.2012     08:55      51735 System.Web.WebPages.xml
-a---        18.03.2010     18:31     941904 System.Xml.dll
-a---        18.12.2012     23:53     244736 ViMuDat.dll
-a---        18.12.2012     23:53     321024 ViMuDat.pdb
-a---        18.12.2012     23:53     125308 ViMuDat.XML
D:\...\bin\de> ls
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        12.01.2011     16:04      15720 System.Web.Helpers.resources.dll
-a---        12.01.2011     17:24      32096 System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll
-a---        12.01.2011     16:04      15208 System.Web.WebPages.resources.dll
```

Comment: Do you actually have these assemblies in your `bin` folder?

Comment: No. I have added a list of the content of the folder to my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are bin deploying MVC 3, there are some assemblies that you have to package up in your deployment.  [Scott Hanselman has a good write up](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) on what and where as well.

If you have copied the assemblies, make user to add then as 'content' to your Visual Studio project.  Then they will be automatically copied into the correct structure in the bin directory when you build.

**EDIT**:
This was the information in the article that helped solve the problem:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies` and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies` contained the missing dlls

Those dlls had to be copied manually to `_bin_deployableAssemblies` of my project.

Answer (score 5):

You might find it easier to just install the packages via [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc).

NuGet is a package manager which makes it easy to install and update dependencies in your project. It is a Visual Studio extension which can be installed from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).

If you are still using ASP.NET MVC3, you can install an older version of the package by using the command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1`.

This will add the binaries as normal references which are included in the `bin` folder when your project is built. This will save you having to do the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` approach. Most other popular 3rd party frameworks (as well as a lot of the new Microsoft Web stack) are also available on nuget.

Comment: Please provide more information. I have no idea how to work with C# / ASP.NET and simply providing buzzwords isn't an answer that helps me (or any other beginner who searches for an answer to this question) to fix the problem. Which nugets? How can they get installed in VS2012?

Comment: @moose follow the link, it will explain what nuget is and how to install and manage packages.